# Vala combobox that shows extra column while selecting value

Tags: linux, combobox, vala

Using the drodown example on [valadoc](https://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.ComboBox.html) I have a dropdown that shows two columns of data for every row. I'm looking to create a combobox that shows the two columns while selecting a value, but hides the second column after selecting. I tried the following:

```
Gtk.ComboBox combo = new Gtk.ComboBox.with_model(list_store);

Gtk.CellRendererText name_renderer = new Gtk.CellRendererText();
combo.pack_start(name_renderer, true);
combo.add_attribute(name_renderer, "text", 0);
Gtk.CellRendererText shortcut_renderer = new Gtk.CellRendererText();
combo.pack_start(shortcut_renderer, true);
combo.add_attribute(shortcut_renderer, "text", 1);

combo.popup.connect(() => {
    combo.add_attribute(shortcut_renderer, "text", 1);
});
combo.popdown.connect(() => {
    combo.clear_attributes(shortcut_renderer);
    return true;
});
```

That gives the following errors though:

```
Gtk-CRITICAL **: 21:46:08.050: gtk_list_store_get_value: assertion 'column < priv->n_columns' failed

GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 21:46:08.050: g_value_transform: assertion 'G_IS_VALUE (src_value)' failed
```

The errors make me think I might be going about this the wrong way, does anyone have any pointers on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Gtk.ComboBox` signals `popup`and `popdown` are keybinding signals which mean they will only be triggered by the keyboard. This also means that there isn't a easy solution for the behavior you're after. The visibility itself is easy though.

The `list_store` needs a new column of boolean type which will control the visibility of the renderer:

```
Gtk.ListStore list_store = new Gtk.ListStore (3, typeof (string), typeof (int), typeof (bool));
```

Then, add the visible attribute to the renderer you want to hide:

```
box.add_attribute (renderer, "visible", 2);
```

Then, the signals that control behavior must iterate the store/model and set the visibility:

```
    list_store.foreach ((model, path, iter) => {
        list_store.set (iter, 2, true); // true to show, false to hide
        return false;
    });
```

Like mentioned, the signals are not appropriate but here is a simple example that will only work with the keyboard (pressing enter or spacebar) to popup the combobox and choosing a different active row will revert visibility. Not exactly what you want but shows what needs to be done on the list store:

```
public class Application : Gtk.Window {
    public Application () {
        // Prepare Gtk.Window:
        this.title = "My Gtk.ComboBox";
        this.window_position = Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER;
        this.destroy.connect (Gtk.main_quit);

        // Create & fill a ListStore:
        Gtk.ListStore list_store = new Gtk.ListStore (3, typeof (string), typeof (int), typeof (bool));
        Gtk.TreeIter iter;

        list_store.append (out iter);
        list_store.set (iter, 0, "Burgenland", 1, 13, 2, false);
        list_store.append (out iter);
        list_store.set (iter, 0, "Carinthia", 1, 17, 2, false);

        // The Box:
        Gtk.ComboBox box = new Gtk.ComboBox.with_model (list_store);
        this.add (box);

        Gtk.CellRendererText renderer = new Gtk.CellRendererText ();
        box.pack_start (renderer, true);
        box.add_attribute (renderer, "text", 0);
        box.active = 0;

        renderer = new Gtk.CellRendererText ();
        box.pack_start (renderer, true);
        box.add_attribute (renderer, "text", 1);
            box.add_attribute (renderer, "visible", 2);
        box.active = 0;

        box.changed.connect (() => {
            Value val1;
            Value val2;

            box.get_active_iter (out iter);
            list_store.get_value (iter, 0, out val1);
            list_store.get_value (iter, 1, out val2);

            print ("Selection: %s, %d\n", (string) val1, (int) val2);
            liststore_set_visibility (list_store, false);
        });

        box.popup.connect (() => {
            print ("PopUp signal...\n");
            liststore_set_visibility (list_store, true);
        });


        box.popdown.connect (() => {
            print ("PopDown signal...\n");
            return true;
        });
    }

    private static void liststore_set_visibility (Gtk.ListStore list_store, bool visible) {
        list_store.foreach ((model, path, iter) => {
            list_store.set (iter, 2, visible);
            return false;
        });
    }

    public static int main (string[] args) {
        Gtk.init (ref args);

        Application app = new Application ();
        app.show_all ();
        Gtk.main ();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm used to using different frameworks with JS that does support these types of features, so I was hoping it would exist in Vala as well.